# RavenDb - CertificateNameMismatchException in secured mode

Tags: .net, ravendb

I have a RavenDB server set up and running in a secured mode. The Server certificate is self-signed and was added after the initial installation was completed. settings.json file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyB9J.png).

I can access server management studio in the browser (Chrome) on 127.0.0.1:8080.
After that, I have issued a client certificate and registered it in Windows.
Then in a simple .NET Framework Console application, I'm trying to store some data into the database.

I use this [sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKECs.png) to create DocumentStorage object. Storage is initializing without any exception, but when I call the session's SaveChanges method, I'm getting `CertificateNameMismatchException`:

*The hostname of the server URL must match one of the CN or SAN properties of the server certificate: CN=ravenDb.test.com, DNS Name=ravenDb.test.com*

What am I doing wrong? 
Is it a server and/or client certificate issue ? or the server itself is incorrectly configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with certificates, you must use your domain name to access the server and not the IP address directly.

Set the configuration property 'PublicServerUrl' to https://ravenDb.test.com:8080 and 'PublicServerUrl.Tcp' to tcp://ravenDb.test.com:38888 and don't forget to set DNS records (or edit the local hosts file) for ravenDb.test.com to point to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Editing host file did the trick. Thanks a lot!